# Does Silverlight download the assemblies every time?

Tags: silverlight

Does a Silverlight application get downloaded every time you visit the site or will it check version/size information and only download a newer version of files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing specific to Silverlight 2 in this regard, the most concise explanation I've read is from [this post](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/18701.aspx) on silverlight.net:

> "Silverlight falls under the same
>   caching rules as any other web
>   content. If the user clears their
>   cache, your xap will have to be
>   downloaded again. In normal
>   circumstances, the xap is downloaded
>   only when changed or when the cache
>   expires."

You can control when the cache expires by following the [steps outlined here](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/11995.aspx):

> You can turn the Enable Content
>   Expiration HTTP header option on for
>   your XAP file. Open IIS Manager, goto
>   Default Web Site and find your Web
>   site for the silverlight project. Find
>   the XAP file under ClientBin. Goto the
>   properties page of the XAP file, on
>   HTTP Headers Tab, Turn on "Enable
>   Content Expiration", click the "Expire
>   Immediately" radio button. Save the
>   change.
>
> This way the new XAP (only there is a
>   new XAP) will get downloaded when you
>   refresh your page without having to
>   close the browser.

This [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307709/how-do-you-force-firefox-to-not-cache-or-re-download-a-silverlight-xap-file) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you configured your webservers headers and how the client configures his browser caching policies.

Usually the browser settings are ok by default. You might want to check your webserver that the appropriate header values for expiration, etags and caching are properly configured. You can use a tool like Firebug to check these settings and use Yslow to meassure other client side performance things.

Comment: So this is determined by standard web settings and nothing that is Silverlight specific then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send pix via silverlight in Hotmail.... It is probably simpler to use some other method unless you are a geek or want to download silverlight every time. It would be nice to have a button and it just works. It is TOO difficult for the ordinary person. KISS... No charge for the technical advice silverlight. Personal experience is ( Tired of silverlight downloading... I just attach pix or publish to Picasa and send a link)