# How to reload default AppDomain in which Silverlight app is running inside browser?

Tags: silverlight, reflection, appdomain

Inside my Silverlight app, i use reflection to load an assembly. While the app is running, the version and content of that assembly can change. I know the moment, when it changes, now I want to trigger the complete reload of the app, so that assembly is reloaded too with the new version. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the page that hosts the silverlight application, so the application is also reloaded: it's just one line:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
```

If you have problems with the browser's cache, check out this question: 
[How do you force Firefox to not cache or re-download a Silverlight XAP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307709/how-do-you-force-firefox-to-not-cache-or-re-download-a-silverlight-xap-file)