# Silverlight application check for update?

Tags: silverlight

Well i have a silverlight application that checks if there are any updates (this is done by calling a webservice).

If there is a update i call Application.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync but the corresponding event CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted is never raised...
Note: this is not a out of browser application.

Comment: Why do you use this functionality when you have no OOB-application? Normally you provide a new Version of your silverlight application by copying the new XAP-file in the ClientBin. The nexttime the webpage of your silverlight app is requested, the new XAP gets downloaded.

Comment: The problem is that the xap doesn't get downloaded it continues to run the old version, sure sooner or later it will download the new version but why should the client have to wait?

Comment: Ok, this is a known problem with caching of Xaps in browsers. I´ll post an answer soon.

Comment: see this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991420/how-to-force-re-download-of-silverlight-xap-file